# Cannot find symbol ID

Tags: java

I have this code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Student {
    private static ArrayList [] Students = new ArrayList [10];    
    private int ID;
        public static void setList(){
            for(int i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
                Students[i] = new ArrayList();
            }
        }
        public void setID(){
            ID = (int) (Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
        }
        public static void addStudent(Student example){
            Students[example.ID % 10].add(example);
        }
        public static void print(){
            for(int i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < Students[i].size(); j++){
                    System.out.println(Students[i].get(j).ID);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
}
```

System.out.println(Students[i].get(j).ID); tells me it cannot find symbol ID. How do I fix this, basically have an array of array list that hold student objects. I want to print the ID of the object. Trynna practice open addressing with array and array lists

Comment: You need to add a type parameter to your ArrayList declaration, so that the compiler knows what type of object you are storing in it.

Comment: Pay attention to your warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified the type of the ArrayList, the elements are stored as type Object. The compiler gives an error as the Object class does not have a member called ID.

This will fix the issue:

```
private static ArrayList<Student> [] Students = new ArrayList [10];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Students[i].get(j)` is of type Object you can cast it to Student type before accessing ID (in your j-loop):

```
for(int j = 0; j < Students[i].size(); j++){
  Student curr = (Student) Students[i].get(j);
  System.out.println(curr.ID);
}
```

Otherwise you need to declare the type of the ArrayList to hold Student objects.

Answer (score 0):

keep `Students[i] = new ArrayList<Student>();`